# Remove duplicates from data downloaded from query in Excel using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, stack, powerquery

I have made a query to download data from a website which has record of past 60 days data. But i need to store values of past 240 days after that whenever new data is fetched the oldest data should get automatically deleted. For that to happen i tried moving 60 days data(Originally recieved in A4:A63) to a new location (A184:A243) and cleared contents A4:A63 first.... then next batch of Data recieved in A4:A63 is moved to location (A124:A183) and cleared contents A4:A63...... then next batch of Data recieved in A4:A63 is moved to location A64:A123 and Cleared contents A4:A63. In this way 240 days of data is stored. After that whenever new batch of Data is fetched from website the latest data gets stored and the oldest one gets deleted its just like First in First out. Here is the code that i made

`

```
Sub ShiftData()
Dim i As Integer
If IsEmpty(Range("A4").Value) = True Then                      '<== To Check new data is present
MsgBox ("No Input to shift")
Else
If Range("A" & 243).Value = "" Then                            '<== Data shifted to last place
Range("A243:A184") = Range("A63:A4").Value
Range("A63:A4").ClearContents
ElseIf Range("A" & 183).Value = "" Then   '<== If last place is occupied data shifted to lastmost empty place
Range("A183:A124") = Range("A63:A4").Value
Range("A63:A4").ClearContents
ElseIf Range("A" & 123).Value = "" Then
Range("A123:A64") = Range("A63:A4").Value '<== If last place is occupied data shifted to lastmost empty place
Range("A63:A4").ClearContents
End If
If Not IsEmpty(Range("A4:A63").Value) = True Then
If Range("A243") <> "" And Range("A183") <> "" _
And Range("A123") <> "" And Range("A63") <> "" Then '<== To check if all places are filled.
Range("A243:A124") = Range("A183:A64").Value       '<== Shifted all data to flush out oldest data
Range("A123:A64") = Range("A63:A4").Value
Range("A4:A63").ClearContents
End If
End If
End If
End Sub`
```

The problem i am facing here is that with every feed from website i get only one to four rows of new data i.e 60th day rest of the data (59 days) is same. So if i stack like this i am getting multiple duplicates which is creating problem in my analysis. I want to get only fresh data to stack up and ignore duplicate data. Let me explain this with an example taking 3 new rows at a time so as to make easy understanding. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj5nj.png)

Comment: Not enough information. Change your query to only download the new data?  Merge new data and old table and remove duplicates?  Filter to only store the most recent 240?  Seems to me you should be able do all you need in PowerQuery without the moving stuff around as you show in your code.

Comment: Ohh.... Actually i used power query first time. I am new to vba.. Can you tell me any resource where i can learn from a to z about power query.

Comment: I'd start with an internet search.  `Power Query for Dummies` returns many hits. I'm sure you can find something there.  I don't have any particular recommendations.